Roll-up summary in classic email template and query return showing 0
I can see roll-up summary number in Salesforce page. However, when I print it in a vf page classic email template, the number is showing 0.
I ran a query in developer console and it also returned as 0.
I checked the object that has the roll-up and made sure I had the sharing access.
I do not know what's wrong. Thank you

this needs more detail for us to be able to help. example data, the schema, the soql, the VF email template

Sorry my bad. There were 2 fields had the same name. I referenced the wrong one.
